# Close a bootstrap row and start new row after every nth containing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row which will be populated by, let's say, blog post thumbnails.

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row thumbs">
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divider" />
  <div class="navigation">navigation</div>
</section
```

I want to close a row, insert hr tag and open a new bootstrap row after every 4th post thumbnail.

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row thumbs">
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divider" />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
  </div>
  <hr class="divider" />
  <div class="navigation">navigation</div>
</section>
```

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can do something like this:

```
var $mainElem = $('.row'),/* adjust selector to suit page*/
    $parent = $mainElem.parent(),
    /* remove children after 4th from existing row */
    $items = $mainElem.children(':gt(3)').detach();

if ($items.length) {
    /* create new row for every 4 items removed above */
    for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 4) {
        var $row = $('<div class="row">').append($items.slice(i, i + 4));
        $parent.append('<hr class="divider">').append($row);    
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qhas5zzc/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Parent of the row is section with class="container". Within that section and right after the row in question there is another row that contains "next - previous" navigation. Right now your code appends the new row after the navigation. Is there a way to attach it before the navigation row?

Comment: A simple solution is just wrap the row in question with another div

Comment: I updated the code. Is there a more semantically correct way to do it, without wrapping the row inside another div?

Comment: Minor adjustment using `before()` instead of `append()`  http://jsfiddle.net/qhas5zzc/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code works, but I found a simpler solution which I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me:

```
var $d = $('.thumbs');
var $p = $('.col-sm-3:gt(3)', $d);
if ($p.length) {
    $('<div class="row thumbs">').insertAfter($d).append($p);
    $('<hr class="divider">').insertAfter($d);
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I guess I'll have to accept your answer as best solution but could you do me a favor and edit your fiddle so that it includes another hr divider before the navigation? I updated the code in my original post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your motivation to wrap each set of columns in a new row, you can style every nth row with straight CSS.

In bootstrap, if you have extra columns that spillover past 12, they just wrap into a new line anyway, so having the new row is usually redundant, although you might have some external reason to keep it in your case.

Either way, here's a CSS solution that adds a page wide horizontal divider every 4 divs:

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/hmbautuL/) & Stack Snippets

```css
.container .row.thumbs div:nth-child(4n) {
    position: static;
}
.container .row.thumbs div:nth-child(4n):after {
    content: ' ';
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row thumbs">
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">navigation</div>
</section>
```

Also, bear in mind that this won't be natively [supported in < IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)